# Reasonable means of security in commercial dealings

Tags: network, physical, e-commerce

I am writing a paper from a legal standpoint and I'm suggesting legislation for a new duty of care for private companies in the safeguarding of customer's personal information. This will not apply to governmental, financial, or healthcare companies.

If you are trying to ensure a decent amount security in your commercial dealings, what would you need to do? I have suggested using encrypted file transfers for the transmission of customer's private information and the encryption of either the whole drive / server, particular partitions, or folders containing personal information. I have suggested that all computers be password protected  (complex password) and if there are varying levels of user privilege that the password for each class be different.

I am no security expert, so I am sure that these sorts of practices leave all sorts of gaps for both physical and network attacks. Could you guys and gal help me with that part? What other sorts of protections should be in place, short of hiring a security administrator?

I do not want the most complex cutting edge sorts of defenses, but just common sense safety procedures for securely protecting customer's private information.

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange for Security!  Here's a link for a tour of the site and how it works.  http://security.stackexchange.com/tour   Thanks for your contribution and again, welcome.  Cheers!

Comment: In order to explain the security practices that could be used to accomplish a good level of security we would need quite a bit of time to list them all in detail, and even more time to understand the consequences that they would have. What I would advise that you do is read the CIS Critical Security Controls along with PCI/DSS, HIPAA and SOX. The CIS Controls will give you some best practices that should be followed while the rest are legal regulations that business entities who deal with sensitive information must follow and be in compliance with.

Comment: Wow really great response, thank you for the leads! I think this will help so much.

Comment: I am curious why you are making recommendations on a topic which you admit to not being particularly familiar with, and at the same time I feel your pain as a lot of what is reasonable or not in security is contextual, and legislation is not great at dealing with contextual appreciations. Definitely look at existing security certifications, especially at the constraints that only apply to some specific service providers / industries.

Comment: My paper is based on a simple notion (whether you agree or not). I am saying that a commercial company should have a fiduciary duty to safegaurd their customers personal data. With that duty, a standard of care must be set. So while I understand there must be a standard and I know companies have been quite unconcerned with safegaurding that data ( ie. ashley madison, wyndham hotel, snapchst, sony, etc...), I basically know what is supposed to happen without knowing exactly how. Which lead me here. I am a student writing a paper, so its not as if I am in any real position of recommendation.

Comment: I think you're trying to flesh out a very exciting and ambitious project/goal, and it corresponds with an issue that the legal profession (ie. lawyers, judges, and academics) are just starting to realize will be a signifigant area within the law: what duties do those who are entrusted a party's sensitive information have to protect that information? Regarding actual substantive standards commercial transactions, common law stuff is even now really just starting to develop & modernize; regulatory and legislative standards --arguably excepting the PCI standards--is barren. That said...

Comment: ...asking what the legally-enforceable substantive requirements for protecting entrusted information is a bit like asking what requirements should be for a surgeon going into a surgery: it can get complicated, diverse in the details, and sometimes technical.  I would definitely say there *is* a generally recognized, consensus set of basics: make sure you're patching everything everywhere, use strong encryption everywhere you can, use strong & unique passwords, use two-factor authentication everywhere you can,  and on and on.  But, to me, there is no one, *definitive* source for those.

Comment: Well my paper does not have to have a perfect suggestion that would pass congress or anything. However, I want it to have real suggestions for us in the legal field to request in remedies for our cases. You guys have helped me immersely with that. Thank you.